# Debugging directly on the device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I don't expect you to correct my code, since it should be working, at least works on emulator. Unfortunately gives different output on the devices. My question is:

How to debug in such cases, when the device is not working  as the emulator, and what could cause that (device model, a custom ROM?)

I heard some rumors some time ago, about possibility using the device instead an emulator somehow connected to the SDK. Could you also confirm or deny that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find it's not uncommon to find little quirks between devices.  Many developers will have several physical devices to test their software on.

You can find information on using a physical device for debugging (including using it inside Eclipse, just as you would the emulator) on the Android website: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. Just put your device into debugging mode, and connect it to the computer with the micro-usb port on the device. You will also need to download the drivers from the manufactures website.

Comment: "You will also need to download the drivers from the manufactures website" (if you are using Windows)

Comment: Ah well, I have never done dev on a mac or linux pc so I wouldnt know.